# Cannot create and save .aj files in eclipse with AJDT plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, aspectj, ajdt

recently I started learning the wonders of AspectJ (http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/faq.php) and decided to use it on a program.

To start I downloaded the lates stable version of aspectJ (http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/downloads.php#stable_release). Then I decided to install AspectJ's plugin for eclipse (http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/whatsnew220/).

I am using eclipse (Version: 3.8.0 Build id: I20120502-2000) and currently I don't have any other plugins installed.

However, when I try to create a .aj file or to save changes in one I always get this error:

```
Save Failed
org.eclipse.ajdt.core.javaelements.AJCompilationUnit.openWhenClosed(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

What is wrong with my installation and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, apparently the eclipse version of the Ubuntu repos (Version: 3.8.0 Build id: I20120502-2000)  works terribly wrong with the given plugin for the version. Not even the eclipse forums managed to answer this correctly.

I updated to eclipse 4.2 and installed the plugin for version 4.2 and now it seems to work properly.

Guess it serves to show me a lesson: Always go to the source.

Comment: Looks like you just learned the hard way not to use the Ubuntu eclipse versions.  They are often out of date and sometimes are incompatible with current releases.  The I20120502-2000 build that you used is not a proper release.  Between that build and the final release of 3.8.0 there was an API change, hence the incompatibility that you found.